# How to get the JSP page name in Java Script included?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have two JSP files a.jsp and b.jsp which shares common ".js" file. Is there any way that I can find from which jsp file the function inside common script is invoked, Without passing any parameter while calling the script function.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to do as you looking for -

But as a alternate way you can give the you file(a.jsp)  as your element id or name and get it after clicking the element like this -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#a").click(function(event) {
    alert(event.target.id);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You could put a hidden variable in each JSP that tells you the file name.

Something like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="jspName" value="a.jsp"/>
```

Then to get it from the javascript:

```
var jspName = $('#jspName').val();
```